# Unable to run fixed rate scheduler in SpringMVC Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run Task scheduler but I get below error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java"  com.mthree.util.App
Error: Could not find or load main class com.mthree.util.App

Process finished with exit code 1
```

## FixedRateScheduler code

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import java.util.Date;

public class FixedRateScheduler {

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
public void run() throws InterruptedException{
    System.out.println("livePrice: "+ new Date());
    Thread.sleep(3000);
   }
}
```

## LivePrice-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

<task:annotation-driven />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="fixedRateScheduler" class="com.mthree.util.FixedRateScheduler" ></bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mthree.*" />
```

## Main Class - App.java

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("LivePrice-servlet.xml");
    }
}
```

## directory structure

[image]